# Query MongoDb for Just month but my date is in string format "DD/MM/YYYY" using moment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

This is my first question here as I have been stuck at a point where I am not able to query my database which has stored dates in "DD/MM/YYYY" String format by using moment

```
_id:5eb3ebfe2faf4a001719b5b1
post:"some random post"
date:"07/05/2020"
time:"11:07:42 AM"
username:"random user"
__v:0
```

I want to display all post done by the user in a current month or last month for query for a single date I can do

date.find({"date":"07/05/2020"},function(err,result){
})

but if I want to query the whole month like */05/2020 how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have saved the date in the string format **you can match it directly with regex**

```
collection.find({ date: { $regex: "\/05\/2020"}} ,function(err,result){ })
```

Working link for above code - https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZE-IneeXb6A

Or If you will use aggregation **you can separate the day, month and year and then match whatever you want**.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
         {

           day: { $substr: [ "$date", 0, 2 ] },
           month: { $substr: [ "$date", 3, 2 ] },
           year: { $substr: [ "$date", 6, 4 ] }
         }
     },
     { $match : { "month" : "05", "year":"2020"} }
   ]
)
```

Working link for above code - https://mongoplayground.net/p/MiG5HUzXI7r

Comment: also can you help me running the same code in mongo console and if I create a drop down for month and year and pass it to the same code as req.query.month and req.query.year they will be replaced in the code with that ?

Comment: I can't understand how you will add drop down in Mongo console, You can pass the req.query.month value in the query where "05" is written, and if you get any problem create a detail question for it too, someone will help you sure.

Comment: they were two questions sorry I meant how to run the same code in mongo console and then that query thing sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

the shortest query I can think of...

```
db.collection.find({
  "date": {
    $regex: "[0-9]{2}\/05\/2020"
  }
})
```